# Docker Microphone Access Error: "No Default Input Device Available"

Tags: python, docker, speech-recognition, microphone

An error occurred: No Default Input Device Available.

```
$ docker run -it speach-container:latest --device /dev/snd/card0:/dev/snd
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/Voicesearch.py", line 50, in main with sr.Microphone() as source: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/speech_recognition/_init.py", line 87, in __init_ 
    device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyaudio/_init_.py", line 812, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```

My script runs successfully on Anaconda, but not within Docker (see error above).

How can I make it work within Docker?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following for making sound devices available in Docker? What does the *pyaudio* documentation say about running it within Docker? Please edit your question, and add links to the docs.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? (Maybe `--device` only works on Linux.)